# Results from a thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

When I did the research for rolling my own thread pool I came across some solutions which were implementing a result storage where you could obtain your function results from a `std::future<T>` object.

As far as I know thread tasks should (as far as possible) be independent, non-blocking and also as far as possibly avoid data sharing.

Blocking the pool should lead to a significant performance loss and is not very desirable.

Wouldn't such a solution work against the model one would try to achieve with a thread pool? Of course there are tasks where you need to know when they are finished, but it seems like a bad idea to store a future for every task you are firing since it decreases the scheduling performance and the execution latency.

Futhermore one would have to clean up not used results anyway, since the
`container< future<T> >` would grow bigger and bigger, which would require another thread or more work for the main thread and even worse it would require locking the result storage to cleanup which would block the pool for a certain time.

I am talking from a general perspective where a thread pool should be as flexible as possible. If you need a result for every task you firing, things look a bit different but my question is focused on a general approach.

Is it desirable to have such an extension or is it better to leave it out for a thread pool which is thought to use in a very broad variety of situations.

Comment: Depends on what you do with your thread pool. For large tasks, the overhead on blocking the pool would be minimal and you'd have very little `future`s. Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: If this is desirable in a threadpool for general use or if going for a regular one the better one

Comment: [Edit] your question to clarify what you want to ask. Remember to give a question statement that can have a clear and as objective as possible answer.